# When we are working with MCSessionState, didChangeState responds very slowly we could not find why

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

We are using following code to inform user about peer to peer connection state. But there is a problem "`labelState.text = state.displayName`" changes label text almost 10 seconds after " `println ("State Changed to \(state.displayName)`" is showed the state. Is there anyone faces the same problem.

```
  func session(session: MCSession!, peer peerID: MCPeerID!, didChangeState state: MCSessionState)
{

    println("State Changed to \(peerID.displayName)")

    labelState.text = peerID.displayName
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MCSessionDelegate` callbacks do not come on the main thread. If you are making UI changes in that function you need to do so on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    labelState.text = state.displayName
}
```

You should also be using `displayName` on the `MCPeerID` object not the `MCSessionState` which is just an enum.