# How to change a views UILabels, UIButtons, UIViews, etc. from a Multipeer Connectivity Session?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipeer-connectivity

It has been 4 days now, and I have been trying to change the view or elements of a view belonging to a peer connected within a multipeer connectivity session.  The session is created and I am able to connect two devices and send data between the two, but whenever I try to change a label nothing happens.  When I used `NSLog` to see what the `label.text` was, it return null.

Here is my session `didReceiveData:` method:

```
- (void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID {
NSLog(@"did receive data, %@", peerID.displayName);
NSDictionary *dict = @{
                       @"data": data,
                       @"peerID": peerID
                       };
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MCDidReveiveDataNotification" object:nil userInfo:dict];

NSArray *arrayFromData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
NSString *gesture = [arrayFromData objectAtIndex:0];
UILabel *tapLabel = [arrayFromData objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *tapString = tapLabel.text;

[_gestureViewController receivedTap:gesture withLabelText:tapString]; }
```

I tried sending the UILabel through with the data along with a normal NSString.  When I call the `gestureViewController` method, 
`receivedTap:gesture withLabelText:tapString`
I am able to `NSLog` the label text, but when I try to set the current viewController's `tapGestureLabel` to the `tapString` text, nothing happens.

Here is my `receivedTap:gesture withLabelText:tapString` method:

```
- (void)receivedTap:(NSString *)gesture withLabelText:(NSString *)labelText {
NSLog(@"%@", gesture);
NSLog(@"%@", labelText);
self.tapGestureLabel.text = labelText; }
```

My idea of dispatching onto main thread:

```
- (void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID {
NSDictionary *dict = @{
                       @"data": data,
                       @"peerID": peerID
                       };
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MCDidReceiveDataNotification" object:nil userInfo:dict];
NSArray *arrayFromData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
UIImage *image = [arrayFromData objectAtIndex:2];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(changeImage:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

My changeImage: selector method:

```
- (void)changeImage:(UIImage *)image {
[_gestureViewController.imageView setImage:image];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [When we are working with MCSessionState, didChangeState responds very slowly we could not find why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923570/when-we-are-working-with-mcsessionstate-didchangestate-responds-very-slowly-we)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session:didReceiveData is called by the Mulitipeer Connectivity Framework from a dedicated thread. You are trying to update a label from this dedicated thread. This is not allowed, you should only access UI elements from the main queue. The solution is to dispatch the piece of code that updates the label to the main queue.

You can do it in receivedTap:withLabelText as follows:

```
- (void)receivedTap:(NSString *)gesture withLabelText:(NSString *)labelText {
    NSLog(@"%@", gesture);
    NSLog(@"%@", labelText);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.tapGestureLabel.text = labelText; 
    });
}
```

Or deal with it earlier in session:didReceiveData:fromPeer

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [_gestureViewController receivedTap:gesture withLabelText:tapString];
});
```

Comment: Awesome, how would I go about dispatching to the main queue / thread?

@PeterFennema

Comment: I added what I thought was dispatching to the main thread above in the description. @PeterFennema

Comment: I saw your update just after I submitted mine, I think it is a matter of personal taste which one to use

Comment: using [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(changeImage:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:NO]; does the trick.